# how do i fix the datepicker function in jquery here?

Tags: jquery, html

Whenever I click on the text field on the html page, it doesn't pop up with a jquery calendar date picker. How do i fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery example</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message" style="display: none;">Welcome to my website</div>
<p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
<input id="date" type="text">


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hide.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

in datepicker.js:

```
$('#date').datepicker({});
```

Comment: Curious, are you using the JQuery UI library for the datepicker? Have you included the files to the JQueryUI library in order to use the datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this mean you have modified datepicket.js to include the line you mentioned?  If that's the case, the datepicker method is running too early. (Before the document has been fully parsed.)  You might try this instead (and remove the change to datepicker.js):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hide.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/datepicker.js"></script> 
<script>
    $(function() {
    $( "#date" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="message" style="display: none;">Welcome to my website</div>
<p id="paragraph">This is a paragraph</p>
<input id="date" type="text">


</body>
</html>
```